# Google Map HTML example from internet won't open on my computer but I can open on Internet URL

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am trying to open html file http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map3.html  from my computer. I can open it on the internet but if I do View Page Source and save it as HTML file I can not open or I can but markers are not shown.
XML used is on location http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example.xml so I downloaded it also and put it in same folder as html file. How to solve this? Because I would like to change this file to suite my needs
Thanks

My HTML (without not necessary things like css, adds.. ) now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 


<script type="text/javascript"> 
//<![CDATA[
      // this variable will collect the html which will eventually be placed in the side_bar 


      // arrays to hold copies of the markers and html used by the side_bar 
      // because the function closure trick doesnt work there 
      var gmarkers = []; 

     // global "map" variable
      var map = null;
// A function to create the marker and set up the event window function 
function createMarker(latlng, name, html) {
    var contentString = html;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        zIndex: Math.round(latlng.lat()*-100000)<<5
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString); 
        infowindow.open(map,marker);
        });
    // save the info we need to use later for the side_bar
    gmarkers.push(marker);

}

// This function picks up the click and opens the corresponding info window
function myclick(i) {
  google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[i], "click");
}

function initialize() {
  // create the map
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(43.907787,-79.359741),
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU},
    navigationControl: true,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
                                myOptions);

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.close();
        });
      // Read the data from example.xml
      downloadUrl("example.xml", function(doc) {
        var xmlDoc = xmlParse(doc);
        var markers = xmlDoc.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          // obtain the attribues of each marker
          var lat = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
          var lng = parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
          var html = markers[i].getAttribute("html");
          var label = markers[i].getAttribute("label");
          // create the marker
          var marker = createMarker(point,label,html);
        }
        // put the assembled side_bar_html contents into the side_bar div
        //document.getElementById("side_bar").innerHTML = side_bar_html;
      });
    }

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(
  { 
    size: new google.maps.Size(150,50)
  });


//]]>
</script> 

  </head> 
<body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onload="initialize()"> 

    <!-- you can use tables or divs for the overall layout --> 
    <table border="1"> 
      <tr> 
        <td> 
           <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 1050px; height: 1050px"></div> 
        </td> 

      </tr> 
    </table> 

    <noscript><p><b>JavaScript must be enabled in order for you to use Google Maps.</b> 
      However, it seems JavaScript is either disabled or not supported by your browser. 
      To view Google Maps, enable JavaScript by changing your browser options, and then 
      try again.</p>
    </noscript> 

//--></script>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this.  The HTML will render but you will have errors galore because of all of the resources that are not located on your local machine (css, js, images, etc.).  You will need to use the Maps API to build your own solution.

Comment: Hi Joe thanks for your answer. I deleted all not necessary thing in html. My map is opened but without markers. Do you see what do I have to delete more to make this work? Because some previous examples which I downloaded worked from my computer

Comment: In the source of the page you are trying to reproduce locally, try to find external js and css resources that you might be able to copy out to a local directory.  Then, wire up their references in the HTML.  This will get you closer.

Comment: Joe you solved it. I only needed one js file and than it worked. If you know maybe solution and for this I will be thankful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013167/google-map-api-3-creating-different-colors-for-markers-from-code-of-api-2  If not thank you anyway! BR